# Inequality. Smth abot AM-GM, but

Tags: inequality

but I`m not indubitably sure. AM-GM doesn`t work. Karamata`s inequality doesn`t work too.

Prove that inequality holds $$ \sum_{k=1}^n (\frac{a_1+\ldots +a_k}{k})^2 \leq 4 \sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2$$

Comment: It is a particular case of Hardy's inequality (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy's_inequality) for $p=2$. Have a look at Pham Kim Hung, *Secrets in inequalities*.

Comment: ty. but I see some help with proofs 

unfortunately, there is no proof in Jack`s profile

Comment: Try to use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in the form $$\frac{a_1^2}{b_1}+\frac{a_2^2}{b_2}+\ldots+\frac{a_n^2}{b_n}\geq \frac{(a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n)^2}{b_1+b_2+\ldots+b_n}.$$ It is a classical inequality.

Comment: http://www.um.es/functanalysis/meetingsold/Zafra/III_Escuela_AF_files/The%20Prehistory%20of%20the%20Hardy%20Inequality.pdf , page 7.

Comment: excuse me, but it is not clear that (8) "obviously" implies (1) for me. could you please explane?